# Pixel-perfect projection matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I'm trying to understand how far should I place the camera position in the lookat function (or the object in the model matrix) to have pixel-perfect coordinates to pass in the vertex shader.

This is actually simple with orthographic projection matrices, but I fail to visualize how the math would work for perspective projection.

Here's the perspective matrix I'm using:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 10000.0f);
```

vertex multiplication in the shader is as simple as:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position.xy, 0.0f, 1.0);
```

I'm basically trying to show a quad on screen that needs to be rotated and show perspective effects (hence why I can't use orthographic projection), but I'd like to specify in pixel coordinates where and how big it should appear on screen.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Specifying the four corners of a trapezoid in pixel coords, and you want some perspective corrected interpolation across the whole thing? If so, focussing on the projection matrix is a bit misleading (One of course could put any arbitrary homogrophy into the projection matrix, but the classical `perspective` functions won't be helpful in that case).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to express vertex coordinates in screen pixel to show a quad on screen at a given pixel position and pixel size so that once roating it, I can still achieve the effects in perspection that i'd get with a normal projection matrix
So basically yes, it's not about perspection persè, nor about the distance, I just want to find a way to specify coordinates in screenpixels and still achieve that effect

Comment: So if I get you right, you just want to specify an _undistorted_ rectangle in pixel coords and later want to rotate it (into depth)?

Comment: Yes i'd like to specify the vertex attribute in the vbo using pixel coordinates but still being able to rotate / scale / translate the object while perspective effects still apply.
So again, I'd like to specify in pixel coordinates it's beginning position and width/height, I don't get how I could do that once I set a viewmatrix and using it in conjunction with a projection matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it can only have pixel-coordinates in one "z-plane" if you want to use a trapezoid view-frustum.

#### Basic Math

If you use a standard camera the basic math for a camera at (0,0,0) would be

for alpha being the vertical fov (45° in your case)

target_y = tan(alpha/2) * z-distance * ((pixel_y/height)*2-1)
target_x = tan(alpha/2) * z-distance * ((pixel_x/width)*aspect-ratio*2-1)

#### Reversing projection

As for the general case. You can "un-project" to find where a point in 3D before all transforms should be to end up on a specific point.

Basically you need to un-do the math.

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position.xy, 0.0f, 1.0);
```

So if you have your final position and want to revert it you do:

```
unprojection =  model^-1 * view^-1 *projection^-1 * gl_Position //not actual glsl notation, '^-1' being the inverse
```

This is basically what functions like `gluUnProject` or `glm::gtc::matrix_transform::unProject` do.

But you should note that the final clip-space after you apply the projection matrix is typically [-1,-1,0] to [1,1,1], so if you want to enter pixel coordinates you can apply an additional matrix to transform into that space.

Something like:

```
               [2/width,        0,     0    -1]
               [      0, 2/height,     0    -1]
screenToClip = [      0,        0,     1     0]
               [      0,        0,     0     1]
```

would transform [0,0,0,1] to [-1,-1,0,1] and [width,height,0,1] to [1,1,0,1]

Also, you're probably best off trying some z-value like 0.5 to make sure that you're well within the view frustum and not clipping near the front or back.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect with a 60 degree field of view. Basically you want to place the camera at a distance from the viewing plane such that the camera forms an equilateral triangle with center points at the top and bottom of the screen.

Here's some code to do that:

```
float fovy = 60.0f; // field of view - degrees
float aspect = nScreenWidth / nScreenHeight;
float zNearClip = 0.1f;
float zFarClip = nScreenHeight*2.0f;
float degToRad = MF_PI / 180.0f;
float fH = tanf(fovY * degToRad / 2.0f) * zNearClip;
float fW = fH * aspect;

glFrustum(-fW, fW, -fH, fH, zNearClip, zFarClip);

float nCameraDistance = sqrtf( nScreenHeight * nScreenHeight - 0.25f * nScreenHeight * nScreenHeight); 

glTranslatef(0, 0, -nCameraDistance);
```

You can also use a 90 degree fov. In that case the camera distance is 1/2 the height of the window. However, this has a lot of foreshortening.

In the 90 degree case, you could push the camera out by the full height, but then apply a 2x scaling to the x and y components (ie: glScale (2,2,1).

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image: Field of view]

Answer (score 0):

I'll extend PeterT answer and leave here the practical code I used to find the world coordinates of one of the frustum's plane through unprojection

This assumes a basic view matrix (camera pos at 0,0,0)

```
glm::mat4 projectionInv(0);
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 500.0f);
projectionInv = glm::inverse(projection);

std::vector<glm::vec4> NDCCube;
NDCCube.push_back(glm::vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f,   -1.0f,     1.0f));
NDCCube.push_back(glm::vec4(1.0f, -1.0f,    -1.0f,     1.0f));
NDCCube.push_back(glm::vec4(1.0f, -1.0f,     1.0f,     1.0f));
NDCCube.push_back(glm::vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f,    1.0f,     1.0f));
NDCCube.push_back(glm::vec4(-1.0f, 1.0f,    -1.0f,     1.0f));
NDCCube.push_back(glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f,     -1.0f,     1.0f));
NDCCube.push_back(glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f,      1.0f,     1.0f));
NDCCube.push_back(glm::vec4(-1.0f, 1.0f,     1.0f,     1.0f));

std::vector<glm::vec3> frustumVertices;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    glm::vec4 tempvec;
    tempvec = projectionInv * NDCCube.at(i); //multiply by projection matrix inverse to obtain frustum vertex
    frustumVertices.push_back(glm::vec3(tempvec.x /= tempvec.w, tempvec.y /= tempvec.w, tempvec.z /= tempvec.w));
}
```

Keep in mind these coordinates would not end up on screen if your perspective far distance is lower than the one I set in the projection matrix

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to know the world-coordinate width of "some item" that you want to display pixel-exact, this ends up being a bit of trivial trigonometry (works for both y FOV or x FOV):

```
S = Width of item in world coordinates
T = "Pixel Exact" size of item (say, the width of the texture)
h = Z distance to the object
a = 2 * h * tan(Phi / 2)
b = a / cos(phi / 2)
r = Total screen resolution (width or height depending on the FOV you want)

a = 2 * h * tan(Phi / 2) = (r / T) * S
Theta = atan(2*h / a)
Phi = 180 - 2*Theta
```

Where b are the sides of your triangle, a is the base of your triangle, h is the height of your triangle, theta is the angles of the two equal angles of the Isosoleces triangle, and Phi is the resulting FOV

[image: triangle]

So the end code might look something like

`float frustumWidth = (float(ScreenWidth) / TextureWidth) * InWorldItemWidth;
 float theta = glm::degrees(atan((2 * zDistance) / frustumWidth));
 float PixelPerfectFOV = 180 - 2 * theta;`